# How can a region matched by "string-match" be commented out with "comment-region"?

Tags: region, comment

I have this code:

```
(when (string-match "^[ ]*\\\\usepackage{url}" (buffer-string))
    (comment-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
```

I tested it on these lines:

```
%% LaTeX file test
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\usepackage{url}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

And I obtained:

```
%% LaTeX file test
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
%% \usepackage{url
}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

I corrected my code to:

```
  (when (string-match "^[ ]*\\\\usepackage{url}" (buffer-string))
    (comment-region (match-beginning 0) (+ (match-end 0) 1)))
```

and got:

```
%% LaTeX file test
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
%% \usepackage{url}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Is it correct to use `(+ (match-end 0) 1)`? Could there be any side effects?

PS I'm curious: Why doesn't the first code work as I expected?

Comment: `@onner-irotsab`: you're mixing functions intended for string usage with functions intended for buffer usage. If you want to change stuff in the buffer, use eg `re-search-forward` to find the text you want to modify, since then `match-end` will be using the 1-based indexing of the buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffer position is counted from **1**, whereas `match-{beginning,end}` uses **0**-based index.

You can test:

```lisp
(when (string-match "^[ ]*\\\\usepackage{url}" (buffer-string))
  (goto-char (match-beginning 0)))
```

The cursor will appear at the end of line.

I suggest you `1+` both:

```lisp
(when (string-match "^[ ]*\\\\usepackage{url}" (buffer-string))
  (comment-region (1+ (match-beginning 0)) (1+ (match-end 0))))
```

Comment: Really they should be using `re-search-forward` and/or `looking-at` rather than extracting the whole buffer contents into a string....

Comment: @rpluim: I just answered OP's question, and what function OP ultimately choose is up to himself. But indeed, you're right, but you should mention OP, otherwise he might miss your comment. Or, feel free to edit my answer to add this alternative :-)

Comment: You answered their question, but it was an x-y problem :-) (and for some reason I'm failing to get his handle to appear in my comment, maybe because it contains a '-')

Comment: I usually use `re-search-forward` or `looking-at`, but I thought it was possible to work on the strings found by `string-match`. So I'll do as I always have, with `re-search-forward` or `looking-at`.

Comment: @rpluim "1-based indexing of the buffer" - Do you mean `0` for the whole match, `1`, `2`, etc. for subexpressions in the regular expression matched by `re-search-forward`?

Comment: No, I mean that buffer positions count starting from 1, and string positions count starting from 0, so when you mix buffer functions with string functions you need to either add or subtract 1 in various places.

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab: I guess you haven't tested the first code snippet in my answer.

Comment: @shynur No, but it was very helpful for me to understand. In fact, before asking my question, I had made a test with `replace-match` (instead of `comment-region`) and in that case you have to apply your suggestion, with `1+` for both positions, otherwise the replacement positions itself at the end of the previous line (and I couldn't figure out why!), but then I tried `comment-region` and saw that the last character of `usepackage{url}` was left out — while at the initial position everything was in order — and I therefore only changed the end position.

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab: So ... any further questions now?

Comment: @shynur It's all clear, thank you very much!

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab: I was asking **whether this answer answered your question**.  If not, since you said "*It's all clear*", you can write your own answer and accept it.